# A function in excel that outputs a Y or an N if all the values are equal for a specific value

Tags: excel, sorting, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

| Components | Serial Num | Market 1 | Market 2 | Market 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 100000000 | N | Y | N |
| 1233 | 100000001 | N | Y | Y |
| 1235 | 100000000 | Y | N | N |
| 1236 | 100000000 | N | Y | N |
| 1231 | 100000001 | Y | Y | Y |

I have a table with over 1k rows each with repeating and different serial numbers. The table's market status (Y or N) is based on an Xlookup that checks the component number and the components market status in another tab. The components market status is accurate. However, since the serial numbers repeat, I'm trying to create a function that can check that if for example, check if Serial number "100000001" is fully qualified Market 2. When it checks Market 2 would be "Y" because all of the "100000001" have a Y in Market 2 but if we do the same for "100000000" it should be "N" because not all of its Market qualify or have "Y". It would be simple there were a small amount of serial numbers but there's over 1k so I was trying to find out if anyone knows if this could even be possible with a spreadsheet of this size. In essence I think it would be like an Xlookup function but it would need to find and check the market status for each Serial number found and then equate if the value is equal to "Y" for each, if they all are then "Y" would come out, otherwise "N".

I hope this makes sense. It's the first time I post on stackoverflow, as such, definitely feel free to let me know if there's anything I can do to make this question clearer or up to standard with StackOverFlow language.

--

I tried using the =FILTER function but when it outputs data it creates a spill since for each serial I would need space below to give me the values. From there I would create an =AND(EXACT([range of the values output],"Y")). This would determine if all the values in the range are equal to Y, if they are "TRUE" would be the output, if not then "FALSE".

I also tried creating an xlookup function that would look for the smallest value. In doing so I would make the Market outputs Y1 and N. What I hoped would happen is that if it came across an "N", it would give me that output first. Since all it takes for the market status of the serial to be "N" is one N in its market. Only way it can be a Y is if they're all the same. Nonetheless, this does not work since XLookup only looks for the value of the serial code and not the market status value.

---

Hey guys thank you all for your support! I figured out a solution to the madness haha. I downloaded Ablebits which has the ability to merge together cells that contain duplicate values and the columns that contain those values are included together separated by semicolons. For instance, if merged all the cells in my example, **serial number** "100000000" would have the following under each market: **Market 1** (N;Y;N), **Market 2** (Y;N;Y), **Market 3** (N;N;N). From there I created 2 color conditions in this order. 1.) if any cell contains an "N" then it would be red indicating that it isn't qualified. 2.) If any cell contains a "Y" then it would be green [since the first rule made those that contain an N red, then this one would only apply to those that have all Y;Y;Y;Y or just 1 "Y" if it didn't repeat. It does not exactly give me an output of Y or N but with all the values in a cell we can distinguish which ones have all qualifications and which don't.

Comment: This reads like the sort of problem you get when you try to implement a database through a spreadsheet, instead of an actual database, which would almost certainly make the problem much simpler to express, much less solve.

Comment: If this could be transferred to a database or if you know any useful databases that I can plug the excel sheet into, could you please share?

Comment: There are lots of databases, take your pick -- it would depend on your OS and demands (on premise, cloud based...). On Windows, SQL Server Express would be a natural choice (the database import/export wizard of Management Studio can import Excel data), Azure in the cloud with Power Automate is another option. If all else fails, exporting the data as CSV and then importing it will work, as most support importing CSV in one form or another without additional tooling. Once in a database, a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING MIN(...) = MAX(...)` will tell you if values are unique.

Comment: Of course, all this does assume you have some knowledge of SQL and databases already. If not, it's worth investing in in any case, but maybe not necessarily right now -- that's something for you to decide.

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the input provided, maybe there is a way to do it in Excel, but we would need to see how the expected output will look like

Comment: Hey guys thank you for your support. I have edited the body with the solution that I found. @David Leal, the desired output was for excel to analyze all the serial numbers and based on their market qualification, output Y or N. (if all the markets were Y then it would be Y. If any of the markets contained an N then it would be N. Similar to an AND statement. For each repeated Serial number that has Market X, they must all be Y, if any N's then it's an N.  I hope this clarifies. Perhaps someone finds an easier solution by this comment.